# wso2 api-m running i docker as non root user

Tags: wso2, openshift, wso2-api-manager

I am looking into running the wso2-am in openshift.
I am trying to run AM but it keeps failing because missing permission to write to the file system.

> Unable to create the directory
>   [/opt/wso2/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/am#sample#calculator#v1]
>
> Unable to create the directory
>   [/opt/wso2/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint]

All examples I see the container is running as root but we want to avoid that and run it as USER 1010.
Can you set a value to make it write to a specified location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it as user with uid 1010 will not help either. You need to set up file system permissions so that directories and files you need to write to have group `root` and are writable by group.

This is necessary because by default under OpenShift your application will run as an assigned uid unique to your project. This is outside of the range of what would be in the `/etc/passwd` file and you cannot predict what it will be in advance. Because it isn't in `/etc/passwd` then it falls back to running as group `root`, thus why you need to satisfy the requirement of file system permissions being group `root` and writable by group.